# One unified SQL query to deal with different select option values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form I have made in PHP which I want to use to record quantities of an item in a MySQL database.

The select lists I am using in my form at the moment.

```
<select name="fish" id="fish">
    <option value="blueFish">Blue Fish</option>
    <option value="redFish">Red Fish</option>
    <option value="pinkFish">Pink Fish</option>
    <option value="greenFish">Green Fish</option>
</select>

<select name="numFish" id="numFish">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

I have a database table, which has the fields numBlueFish, numRedFish, numPinkFish and numGreenFish.

I would like to have one SQL insert / update query, although I am unsure how to do that.

My best attempt so far is to read in fish and numFish through POST and then have 4 different SQL queries, one for each color fish.

Is there a simpler way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: As @podiluska has indicated, it would be better to restructure your tables, if possible. What you've got at the moment is sometimes referred to as "attribute-splitting" - where you've got two columns (or tables, etc) that really represent the same thing (counts) when they should really be a single column/table, and a new column that represents the *value* that was previously placed in the column/table *name*.

Answer (score 2):

You should start by normalising your database to have a table with `(Colour, FishCount)` and any other fields that you have.  You may also wish to have a table of Colours that you join to this table, and use to populate your list of acceptable colours.

That way you can write simpler queries, and not have to restructure your database when you add a new coloured fish. eg:

```
Update FishColourCount
set FishCount = 3
where Colour = 'blue'
```

Comment: Perhaps OT, but why is it better to have a table with many records for one id, as opposed to a table with only 1 record for each id. Given that there is a fixed number of colored fish, isn't the latter more efficient when retrieving info?

Comment: Perhaps, yes, for that single query. But for other queries, such as "Find the average number of fish per owner", or "for every owner, tell me their most popular colour", etc, then a normalised structure will lead to much simpler querying.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is the best, expecially for readability...

However you can try with:

```
"UPDATE table 
 SET numBlueFish = numBlueFish + " . ($_POST['fish'] == 'blueFish' ? $_POST['numFish'] : 0) . ", 
     numRedFish = numRedFish + " . ($_POST['fish'] == 'redFish' ? $_POST['numFish'] : 0) . ", 
     numPinkFish = numPinkFish + " . ($_POST['fish'] == 'pinkFish' ? $_POST['numFish'] : 0) . ", 
     numGreenFish = numGreenFish + " . ($_POST['fish'] == 'greenFish' ? $_POST['numFish'] : 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the column a variable.
For for example select which column you are updating from 'Fish' posted variable.
But as podiluska mentioned, you should probably normalize the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with podiluska, but in case u cant normalize table you can use somethink like this

```
switch ($_POST['fish']) {
    case 'blueFish' :
    case 'redFish' :
    case 'pinkFish' :
    case 'greenFish' :
        $field = 'num' . ucfirst($_POST['fish']);
        break;
}

$value = (int) $_POST['numFish'];
$query = "UPDATE table SET {$field} = {$value}";
```